# Are the iLife install discs still compatible with Mountain Lion?

Tags: macos, upgrade

I'm about to install Mountain Lion to my Macbook Pro. But before I go for an upgrade, I've search some information about the Mountain Lion. Some says that their iLife was removed after upgrading. I'm using iLife 11 on Mac OSX Snow Leopard, and I still have the Application discs.

Are the iLife install discs still compatible with Mountain Lion?

Answer (score 1):

Your version of iLife is fully compatible with Mountain Lion. It is actually the [current version](http://www.apple.com/ilife/) that ships with Mountain lion. There is no reason that installing Mountain lion should overwrite or otherwise remove your version of iLife. A standard installation should always preserve all of your applications and user settings.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer, as given by **soxman**, is yes: the iLife apps will work, and even the DVD edition can be updated to the latest version.

However, **the signing certificate used on some versions** -- definitely on the MBP 2011 OEM disc -- **has expired**, resulting in a warning or immediate installation failure.

In the latter case, a selective package installer such as the nag-screen shareware **[Pacifist](http://www.charlessoft.com/) will easily work around the issue**.